# From an Object's Array's Element, how can I access the Object's properties/methods. Js

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have object Foo

```
var Foo = function() {
  var array = [];
  var method = function() {return true;};
};
```

And Foo.array will contain another object:

```
var Bar = function() {
  var method = function() {/*Perform Foo.method() here */ };
};
```

So for var foo.array = [new Bar()];

How can I access foo object from the bar instance array element.

Comment: You can't. In Javascript, object properties do not know anything about their parent.

Comment: you need to pass `foo` as a `Bar()` parameter, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is incorrect:

```
var foo.array = [new Bar()];
```

you need to do this:

```
var foo = new Foo();
```

and then you can do this:

```
foo.array = [new Bar(foo)];
```

but you need to modify your Bar `class` so you can store a reference to `foo`, let's say something like this:

```
var Bar = function(foo) {
  // here you will save an object reference
  // that will be accesible for all function scope
  var _foo = foo;

  var method = function() {
     _foo.method(); // an example calling
  };
};
```

and then now you can access to `foo` variable inside your `Bar` class and do whatever you need with it. But your `Foo.method()` and `Foo.array` are not visible, you need to make them public:

```
var Foo = function() {
  this.array = [];
  this.method = function() {return true;};
};
```

Comment: short answer: yes. Why? i cannot think of a place where says that you cannot store an `object`'s reference inside another `object`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think it will work well. I don't know if you are familiar with Ember JS, but your suggestion is similar to how their models use object.belongsTo('parentObject') or object.hasMany('childrenObjects')

Answer (score 0):

I think rearranging things so it's more object oriented will help you get around this. Right now, `Foo` looks to be a function instead of an actual object. Putting it inside an object and then having `Foo` return that object will give you access to it. See below:

```
function foo () {
    var obj = {
        array: function () {
            var array = [];
            return array;
        }
    };
    return obj;
}

var bar = function () {
    var method = function () { 
    foo().array(); 
    };
}
```

You may want to consider passing a parameter 'arrayContents' for example, to the array method.